# How to configure host machine to access Apache ServeName in Docker

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

How to configure my Dockerfile or docker-compose for that my host machine can resolve a ServerName like http://myapp.env instead http://localhost:8080?!

I tried to configure my local hosts file with the ip from container, but without success, like this

172.20.0.3 goforce.env

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

LABEL maintainer="rIckSanchez"
LABEL project="MyApp"

COPY .docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
COPY .docker/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY . /srv/app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    wget \
    nano \
    git \
    unzip \
    iputils-ping

# Install PHP extensions deps
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        g++ \
        unixodbc-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libaio-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        freetds-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        openssl

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
        --install-dir=/usr/local/bin \
        --filename=composer

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_dblib --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    && pecl install sqlsrv-4.1.6.1 \
    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-4.1.6.1 \
    && pecl install redis \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
            iconv \
            mbstring \
            intl \
            gd \
            mysqli \
            pdo_mysql \
            pdo_dblib \
            soap \
            sockets \
            zip \
            pcntl \
            ftp \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
            sqlsrv \
            pdo_sqlsrv \
            redis \
            memcached \
            opcache


RUN a2enmod rewrite negotiation

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/app

RUN service apache2 restart
```

My docker-compose

```
version: "3"
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
services:
  app:
    image: laravel-app
    container_name: laravel-app
    networks:
      - app-tier
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app

  redis:
    image: redis:4-alpine
    container_name: laravel-redis
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 16379:6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

volumes:
  redis:
    driver: "local"
```

My 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.env
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /srv/app/public
    <Directory "/srv/app/public">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker web server port 80 is mapped to your localhost port 8080. To go around the the fact that localhost can't see the docker private network. The dns won't be able to map traffic to certain port, but you can access goforce.env:8080 by adding following line to your /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 goforce.env
```

If you want to use just goforce.env, you should change your docker-compose:

```
ports:
  - 8080:80 -> to 80:80
```

or you could run apache proxy on your host machine and point port 80 to 8080 (if you must run apache on host and docker server at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Try using nginx for reverse proxy of the application . Check this url

[Multiple docker containers accessible by nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654135/multiple-docker-containers-accessible-by-nginx-reverse-proxy)